# How to change the state of a static variable that will be passed to another widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am writing this quizz app where the screen will display a question and 4 suggestions to it ( there are 5 questions ) and when they pick an answer ( clicking on any listtile ) the screen will display the next question and the suggestions corresponding.

I tried to achieve this creating a list of type Info called screens , then the elements of the list will be initialized by the Info constructor that got the question and the 4 suggestions as properties .

The screen that will be first displayed is Info.screens[Info.indx] , and i want the index to increment whenever the user clicks on a listtile acheiving this using the setState within the onTap property of every listtile .

As showing in this following code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'Info.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(Quizz());
}

class Quizz extends StatefulWidget {
  const Quizz({super.key});

  @override
  State<Quizz> createState() => _QuizzState();
}

class _QuizzState extends State<Quizz> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: Info.screens[Info.indx],
        
      );
  }
}


//the two files are separate

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class Info extends StatefulWidget {

  
  
  static int indx = 2;
  late int i ;

  static List screens = [
    Info(question: "qst1", sgt1: "a", sgt2: "b", sgt3: "c", sgt4: "d"),
    Info(question: "qst2", sgt1: "a", sgt2: "b", sgt3: "c", sgt4: "d"),
    Info(question: "qst3", sgt1: "a", sgt2: "b", sgt3: "c", sgt4: "d"),
    Info(question: "qst4", sgt1: "a", sgt2: "b", sgt3: "c", sgt4: "d"),
    Info(question: "qst5", sgt1: "a", sgt2: "b", sgt3: "c", sgt4: "d"),
  ];

  String question , sgt1 , sgt2 , sgt3 , sgt4;

  
  Info(
    {
      super.key,
      required this.question,
      required this.sgt1,
      required this.sgt2,
      required this.sgt3,
      required this.sgt4,
      }
      );

  @override
  State<Info> createState() => _InfoState();
}

class _InfoState extends State<Info> {

 

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    widget.i = Info.indx;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Quizz App" , style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
        ),),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 19, 15),
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        
      ),

      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(221, 165, 12, 12),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 25, 10, 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(widget.question , style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,fontSize: 21
                        ),),
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 23, 18),
                          blurRadius: 20
                        )]
              ),
            ),


            SizedBox(height: 30,),
            
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 23, 18),
                          blurRadius: 20
                        )
                      ]
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () { setState(){
                        widget.i++;
                        Info.indx ;
                      }
                      },
                      mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      title: Center(
                        child: Text(widget.sgt1 , style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,fontSize: 21
                        ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 23, 18),
                          blurRadius: 20
                        )]
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () { setState(){
                        widget.i++;
                        Info.indx = widget.i;
                        }
                      },
                      title: Center(
                        child: Text(widget.sgt2 , style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,fontSize: 21
                        ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 23, 18),
                          blurRadius: 20
                        )]
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () { setState(){
                        widget.i++;
                        Info.indx = widget.i;
                        }
                      },
                      title: Center(
                        child: Text(widget.sgt3 , style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,fontSize: 21
                        ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 23, 18),
                          blurRadius: 20
                        )]
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () { setState(){
                        widget.i++;
                        Info.indx = widget.i;
                        }
                      },
                      title: Center(
                        child: Text(widget.sgt4 , style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,fontSize: 21
                        ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried all the ways to do this but nothing changes , i even when i added print("Incremented") within the onTap nothing appeared on the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

StatefulWidgets are immutable simple configurations and we do not save state variables in these classes. You should define your state variables in the State class (InfoState) of the StatefulWidget, and whenever you change them then you can setState with the new values of these variables.
Of course this is the simplest way of state management.
Please check out sample documentations on official website and tutorials online to better understand state management concepts.